# Footable Bootstrap Accordian Gridview no Expand Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, footable

Originally I was trying to get the FooTable Expand button to appear on the CommandField column, but I have given up on that.
Now I am trying to get it to appear on the First BoundField column, but it is not showing.  The Gridview is working as a FooTable is supposed to work, with the exception of the missing Expand (Plus/Minus) Button.

My HTML Column code is:

```
    <Columns>
<%-- '--- Edit/Delete Gridview's Left-most "Column" -----%>
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Font-Size="10pt">
   <ControlStyle Font-Size="10pt" Font-Bold="True"></ControlStyle>
   <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
</asp:CommandField>

<%-- '--- Gridview's 2nd Column from Left -----%>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Device_ID" HeaderText="Device ID" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="Device_ID">
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15%" />
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" />
  <ControlStyle Width="80%" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

The VB Codebehind code is:

```
 GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = True
    If Not GridView1.HeaderRow Is Nothing Then
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Attributes("data-class") = "expand"

        ' ''Attribute to hide other columns
        For i As Integer = 2 To GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
            If i <= 4 Then
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Attributes("data-hide") = "phone"
            Else
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Attributes("data-hide") = "phone,tablet"
            End If
        Next

        ''Adds THEAD and TBODY to GridView.
        GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    End If
```

This VB code appears to be working because when I look at the Rendered Page I see the **data-class="expand"** & **data-hide="phone"** in the thead columns where I expect them to be.   But when I reduce the Browser 'real estate' the Expand (Plus/Minus) button does not appear anywhere - let alone where I expect it to be on the first BoundField column ( **Gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells(1)** ).

[image]

What am I missing and/or what do I need to do in order to get the Expand (Plus/Minus) Button to appear?

EDIT ------------------------
One comment below mentions the "icons" and I didn't know anything about that.   But I have looked closer and found a reference within the file:

```
footable.bootstrap.css
```

In it there is a class:  **fooicon**
But in that definition it references:
**font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;**

However in my font folder I have files named:

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot  
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg  
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf  
glyphicons-halflings-regular.wolf  
glyphicons-halflings-regular.wolf2
```

Noting the difference between the font name declared in the .css file and the file names in my font folder (the dashes and the 'regular') -- do I need to change something in my .css declaration?

Your advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the position of icons and try to set it proper with CSS

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by:  "Check the position of icons".   None of the FooTable website references mention the need for "icons"   The one single line which is supposed to enable the display of the Expand (Plus/Minus) button is:   GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Attributes("data-class") = "expand"   See where is says: "//Attribute to show the Plus Minus Button."  on  https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-Responsive-GridView-for-Mobile-Phone-Tablet-and-Desktop-display-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: If you can create some fiddle or codepen snippet than it will be easier for me to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.  I tried to set up a Fiddle, but I don't see where/how I can put in the VB Codebehind to put in the Header Cell Attributes data-class="expand" & data-hide="phone" and then convert the Gridview into a Table.